# Flutter predefine the textformfield format for date

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I would like to have a TextFormField (or something similar) in Flutter to guide the users to enter date. I want to predefine the format in the TextFormField, such as `__/__/____`, and the user can only change values where it is `_`. For example, when a user enters 05 for date, it will be `05/__/____`. And when a user enters `01012023`, it will be `01/01/2023`.

Not sure if it is easy to configue or if there is already a similar component?

Thank you.

Comment: Create 3 separate `TextFormField`(`TextField` if you want) for each `month`, `date`, `year` and draw dashes in between them.
Then use focus node to move to the next one if valid.
If empty, show two underscore.
Thats how I did it

and don't forget to remove borders from the `TextFormField`.